# How to convert every other letter in word using python?

Tags: python, string

I want to write a program that prompts the root user to enter the word and then capitalizes (converts to a capital letter) every other letter from the word. So if a user enters the word rhinoceros, the program will print rHiNoCeRoS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `case = ['lower','upper']; print(*(getattr(c, case[i%2])() for i,c in enumerate(s)),sep='')`

Comment: Or maybe: `case = [str.lower,str.upper]; print(*(case[i%2](c) for i,c in enumerate(s)),sep='')`

Answer (score 0):

Well, strings are immutable, so you will have to build a new string. One way would `str.join` the elements produced by a conditional generator that uppercases characters based on their index:

```
# inp = input()
inp = 'rhinoceros'
outp = ''.join(c.upper() if i%2 else c for i, c in enumerate(inp))
print(outp)
# 'rHiNoCeRoS'
```